# Netbeans 13, Local History

Tags: netbeans

I use Netbeans for general coding and the local history. But Netbeans only stores the history for specific time and then it is deleted. Any ideas, how I can prevent that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Tools > Options > Team > History and adjust the "Local History" settings there:

[image]

By default, NetBeans keeps 7 days of local history.

---

If you have not already considered it, I would recommend using a [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) system such as Git, Mercurial, or Subversion. These require some initial set-up and learning, to get the most out of them. They can be integrated with NetBeans.

But the more basic NetBeans "local history" feature can still be very useful, on its own.